# How to integrate MS Outlook with Adempiere?

Tags: outlook, adempiere

Let me know how to proceed the integration of **MS outlook** with **Adempiere ERP&CRM**. My requirement is that Adempiere user lists are maintained in outlook.if i customize/add contact means this change must reflect to Adempiere user table.Please guide me to proceed. (Now i have finished the steps instructed in http://wiki.adempiere.net/Adempiere_Web_Services.)

Comment: Ms Outlook having user id's and passwords? How you are going to validate it ?

Comment: Is it period basic sync-up or every login hit you need to connect to the MS outlook ?
If it is period basic sync-up then you go for the JACOB Bridge ? If it is every login hit you need to check the outlook users then go for the web-services?

Comment: im in second case: every login hit you need to connect to the MS outlook.

Answer (score 0):

In ADempiere you will find 'Business Partner' as a primary counter part of Contacts in Outlook that you need to sync with.

> The Business Partner window allows you do define any party with whom you transact. This includes customers, vendors and employees.[^](http://wiki.adempiere.net/ManPageW_BusinessPartner)

Write your own web-service to directly fetch the data from database. You can also join your query with other related tables e.g. join with ad_user table if you want to select only those who have their login id

```
  SELECT u.name, u.email 
    FROM ad_user u, c_bpartner b 
    WHERE u.c_bpartner_id=b.c_bpartner_id
```

In case of a vendor supplier or any other company, Business partner may also have a primary contact person that you might also need to extract see the tab: Contact (User) [see here](http://wiki.adempiere.net/ManPageW_BusinessPartner)

For Outlook development first you need to select an API or technology for developing Outlook solutions. If you are not familiar with MAPI don't go with it and use managed Outlook object model or PIA.